# How to catch Python "coroutine was never awaited" warning and trigger an EXCEPTION

Tags: python, asynchronous, exception, async-await, io

I'm writing a python test suite which makes frequent use of async io. As a result I have a number of test fixture functions which are defined as "async" and must be called with "await..." to be useful.

However, I **frequently** forget the "await" when writing a test. When the test is run, it may output quite a bit of logging information, and somewhere in the middle there will be a single line which says "**RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MyFixture.DoSomething' was never awaited**".

It's easy to miss this warning in the log, and wonder why the test didn't do what it was supposed to.

Is it possible to turn this runtime warning into a fatal exception which will stop the execution in a really obvious way, or allow me to catch it and turn on a siren and flashing lights or something?

This seems like an obvious question, but I haven't found any answer by googling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W).

> Warning control. Python’s warning machinery by default prints warning messages to sys.stderr.
> -Werror    # Convert to exceptions

When calling python from the command line, add `-Werror` to make all warnings (runtimewarning, deprecationwarning, etc) count as exceptions.
This should turn your asynchronous runtimewarning into a runtimeerror (or exception, i'm not sure which).

Comment: Well, that works... but it's not a very practical solution. I need users to be able to run the tests easily; having to use "python -Werror .\run_tests.py" is a bit messy and confusing. Is there any way to specify this option in a module-level configuration file or similar?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but there should be an environment variable you can edit that changes the default python warning level (which could be controlled with `os.environ` programmatically). Not sure about config files.